# wrong wp_nav_menu displayed

Tags: wordpress

my url looks like this:
http://domain.com/?s=searchquery&post_type=qa_faqs

that page lists search results for "searchquery".

i then get the post type with

```
$post_type = $_GET['post_type'];
```

it echoes correctly

```
echo $post_type;
// Provides: qa_faqs
```

i then do an if/else to display a different menu via wp_nav_menu when $post_type is qa_faqs.

```
if ( $post_type == 'qa_faqs' ) {
  echo 'we got qa_faqs over here';
  wp_nav_menu(array('menu' => 'meta_menu', 'items_wrap' => '<dl id="%1$s" class="nice tabs vertical %2$s">%3$s</dl>', 'walker' => new sidenav_walker ));
} else {
  echo 'no qa_faqs in da house';
  wp_nav_menu(array('menu' => 'service_menu', 'items_wrap' => '<dl id="%1$s" class="nice tabs vertical %2$s">%3$s</dl>', 'walker' => new sidenav_walker ));
}
```

now to the funny part:

even though the page echoes 'we got qa_faqs over here', it displays the service_menu.

why´s that?

Comment: Take both menus out of the logic and output them outside, are they the same?

Comment: they are not the same, that´s why i want to show meta_menu if $post_type is 'qa_faqs' and service_menu if $post_type is not 'qa_faqs'.

Comment: I am having the same problem (http://pastebin.com/H0GzFJz2) they both output the social menu when the top one should be outputting the header menu, very odd.

Comment: This was really driving me nuts =)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Found it - http://codex.wordpress.org/Navigation_Menus

Same problem was driving me nuts aswell.

Use 'theme_location' instead of 'menu' to point to which menu you want to output.

Comment: This helped me, thanks! Could you explain why it worked?

Comment: It's been a while, so I don't know if i remember correctly, but i think 'menu' is the name of the menu you want to use and 'theme_location' is where you want to put that menu

Comment: I also stumbled upon this problem. I think it took about 1 hour before I actually solved it. +1

Comment: I was using `'menu' => 'menu_name'`. Seemed logical! `'theme_location' => 'menu_name'` works perfectly.

Comment: Thank you sir, this helped me.

Answer (score 5):

Try targetting the specific menu with something like:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'Your Menu Name' )); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you dont have any items on the meta_menu. Please create menu under Appearance section and assign it. :)

Comment: both the service_menu and meta_menu are properly set up in the backend and are working as expected in other template files.